# Accessing fragment objects from AsyncTask separate thread

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, java-threads

I'm calling an asyncTask from a fragment to do some networking. While it is running i need to be able to disable the button in a fragment until AsyncTask calls onPostExecute.

my only problem is that i cannot access buttons like this from doInBackground:

```
Button mButtom = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
```

it comes up with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have our function called runOnUIThread

```
@Override protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
    //do your action
      }
    });
    return "";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked perfectly! But just out of curiosity can you explain what does "The current thread must have a looper!" means. I looked up Android loopers but didn't get a concept of that.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the UI from  an `AsyncTask`, override one or multiple of `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate`. The latter will be called whenever you call `publishProgress` in `doInBackground`.